# What is relation between a particular root of two polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, cubics

We have $$x^3+(m+n+p-1)x^2-((m+n)(1-p)+2p-1-mn)x-(p-1)(m-1)(n-1)=0$$ in which $m,n\ge2, p\ge1$ are natural numbers. All the three roots of this cubic are positive. Let $\lambda$ be the least of them.

> How $\lambda$ changes with respect to $m,n$? (keeping $m+n,p$ fixed)
>
> For given values of $p$, how to compare corresponding $\lambda$'s?

Comment: Start by determining if there must be a root between one and zero.  If there is, you may proceed by attempting to use approximations that make use of the constant the most and terms with $x^n$ becoming insignificant for $0\le x\le1$.

Comment: @Simple Art can you help me [here] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656617/coefficents-of-cubic-polynomial-and-its-least-root) please. I am not getting the answer provided there.

Comment: "All the three roots of this cubic are positive." No, this is not true. Moreover, it can be proven that there is no such a cubic equation of the form whose three roots are all positive. So, $\lambda$ cannot be defined.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are still interested in this question, but seeing [your another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656617/coefficents-of-cubic-polynomial-and-its-least-root) which seems the case where $p=2$ in this question, it seems to me that the coefficient of $x^2$ in this question has to be $-m-n-p+1$, not $m+n+p-1$. Anyway, the current cubic equation cannot have three positive roots as I've already commented.