# Coefficents of cubic polynomial and its least root

Tags: roots, cubics

Let $x^3-(m+n+1)x^2+(m+n-3+mn)x-(m-1)(n-1)=0$, 
be a cubic polynomial with positive roots, where $m,n \ge2$ are natural nos. For fixed $m+n$, say $15$, it turns out that least root of the polynomial will be smallest in case of $m=2,n=13$ i.e the case in which difference is largest.

I checked it for many values of $m+n$ and same thing is coming out. It seems that observation is right. How to prove it?

I noticed that coefficient of x and constant are also of largest modulus when difference between $m,n$ is largest. Does it help anyway?

Comment: The symmetric functions of the roots of this cubic equation are expressible in terms of the coefficient in m and n. Fixing m+n means you are fixing sum of the roots....so you can solve the other two roots and check your assertion explicitly.

Comment: In a polynomial $(x - a) (x - b) (x- c)$, the coefficient of $x$ is just $-(a+b+c)$, while the constant is $-abc$ which may explain your second observation (once you've looked at DBS's comment).

Comment: @DBS, can you write it as an explicit answer please.

Answer (score 1):

**Some Remarks:**
There is an explicit formula to solve cubic equations  [here](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac11/fac11.html) . So you can always use it and analyze the roots in a brute-force way. I will follow a somewhat simpler method.  I will assume that : 
in the cases you are interested in you always have three (not necessarily distinct) real roots... otherwise the question isn't saying anything useful.

**The method:**
Let $f(x) = x^{3} + (m+ n+1) x^{2} + (mn + m + n -3) x - (m-1)(n-1)$.
The idea is we are interested in the smallest real root of $f(x)$ and this will be somewhere in the left of the smallest root of $f^{'}(x)$ (the derivative)- which is also real. So we want to minimize the roots of $f^{'}(x)$.

*This is just a simple application of Mean Value theorem.*

But $f^{'}(x)$ is a quadratic function whose roots are obtained by quadratic formula. Let us use new variable : $ p = m+ n$ and $q = m-n$. 
Then we have $$f^{'}(x) = 3x^{2} - 2(p+1)x +(\frac{p^{2}-q^{2}}{4} + p -3).$$

In the question $p$ is fixed so it is a constant. Using the quadratic formula you can check that the minimum value of the real roots are achieved when the discriminant $$D(q): 4\left ( (p+1)^{2} - 3(\frac{p^{2}-q^{2}}{4} + p -3)\right)$$ (as a function of $q$ since $p$ is fixed anyway) is maximized. 
This is what you observe in your  calculations.

**EDIT**
Regarding the discussion OP mentioned in the comments here is full set of solution to the equation $x^{3} - 16x^{2} = 68x -75 = 0$ using the software  [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/). *It is free and can be used online so anyone can try it and it is wonderful!*
The solutions are: 
$$ 
\left[x = -\frac{1}{2} \, {\left(\frac{1}{18} i \, \sqrt{14141} \sqrt{3} + \frac{425}{54}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}} {\left(i \, \sqrt{3} + 1\right)} + \frac{26 i \, \sqrt{3} - 26}{9 \, {\left(\frac{1}{18} i \, \sqrt{14141} \sqrt{3} + \frac{425}{54}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}} + \frac{16}{3}, \;  x = -\frac{1}{2} \, {\left(\frac{1}{18} i \, \sqrt{14141} \sqrt{3} + \frac{425}{54}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}} {\left(-i \, \sqrt{3} + 1\right)} + \frac{-26 i \, \sqrt{3} - 26}{9 \, {\left(\frac{1}{18} i \, \sqrt{14141} \sqrt{3} + \frac{425}{54}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}} + \frac{16}{3}, \; x = {\left(\frac{1}{18} i \, \sqrt{14141} \sqrt{3} + \frac{425}{54}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}} + \frac{52}{9 \, {\left(\frac{1}{18} i \, \sqrt{14141} \sqrt{3} + \frac{425}{54}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}} + \frac{16}{3}\right]
.$$

Comment: According to this answer, if (m-1)(n-1) is replaced by some other constant 'k' such that roots of qubic are still real. Same observation must hold but that is not true.

Comment: Replace (m-1)(n-1) by 5(m+n) and put m,n=8,7 and 9,6 we'll get a contradiction to this answer. I don't get how minimizing roots of $f'(x)$ will minimize smallest root of $f(x)$. Please explain.

Comment: By mean value theorem, two real roots of f'(x) lie between the three real roots of f(x). So the smallest root of f' is a natural bound on the smallest root of f. This is what is used in this answer.

Comment: You can check with the formulas for roots of cubic equations (linked in the answer) or any standard algebra software that when m,n=8,7 and you replace the constant term by 5(m+n) you end up getting two complex roots and one real root. In this case there is no least root.... In any case changing the constant term will only shift the graph of f vertically. The argument regarding the position of real roots with respect to the roots of the derivative will still be valid....(as long as all three roots are real).

Comment: When m,n=8,7 and constant term is 5(m+n), cubic is $x^3-16x^2+68x-75$ and its root are 9.8925, 4.3723, 1.7332  For m, n=9,6 cubic is $x^3-16x^2+66x-75$ and its roots are 10.2984, 3.7697, 1.9319

Comment: Well you may want to check the edited answer above for exact solutions to the equation $x^{3} -16x^{2} + 68x -75$ in any case their numeric approximations are : 4.37433002935733 - 8.88178419700125e-16*I, 1.73318207967413 + 4.44089209850063e-16*I and 9.89248789096854.  This matches with the numbers you posted except that I suspect your software is truncating the complex part which is extremely small (of the order of e^(-16)).

Comment: complex roots of a real polynomial occur in conjugate pairs.

Comment: Also you can think of $f(x)=x^2+(m+n)x+mn$ then for fix m+n say 7, $f'(x)$ always has only one root but notice that for different values of m,n with sum 7, roots of f(x) are changing.